# How to get microphone to work on acer aspire one 722

Tags: acer, microphone, aspire

I have an acer aspire 722, I recently went to use gmail/talk as well as empathy and realized that the microphone does not work. I checked the sound settings, adjusted microphone level, did a mic test but the level indicator showed no bars.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are we talking about here?

Answer (score 3):

Now my speakers work & mic work:

- I installed `linux-image-3.4.0-999-generic-pae_3.4.0-999.201205070447_i386.deb`
- and then adjusted mic boost in alsamixer
- `sudo alsactl store`
- added to startup applications: `alsactl restore`

Comment: `linux-image-3.4*`? All that's available to me is up to 3.2 in Precise.

Comment: in precise, you can usually install newer kernels through the hardware enablement stack because precise is LTR

Answer (score 1):

You need to unmute the microphone input. Try running `alsamixer` in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), and checking it there. If it's muted or low, you can unmute and/or increase it in `alsamixer`.

Answer (score 0):

- Open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:  `alsamixer`.
- Press <kbd>F6</kbd> and choose **1 HDA ATI SB** as a sound card to configure by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- To see the mic-related sliders, press <kbd>F5</kbd> and move the cursor keys to the right, only the outermost three sliders need to be set to a level of 56 by pressing the Up key
- Then, by pressing the <kbd>C</kbd> key on each of the three sliders, the volume level of each right channel needs to be put to 0
- finally, quit alsamixer by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AspireOne522#Microphone

After each reboot, you may need to toggle the Mute button by:

- Click on the speaker icon on top right panel and choose **Sound Settings...**
- Click on the Input tab (second from left) and adjust input volume to *Unamplified 100%* and say something to see if the input level indicator moves enough. If not, click on *Mute* to mute and then click again to unmute.

Hope this helps