# Alsamixer: howto disable auto-mute mode

Tags: sound, alsa, acer, aspire

[image]

I've tried do undo this but not able to get it disabled. My sound settings need to be redone every boot up as well, but asking that question as well would get neg. feedback.

[How to get microphone to work on acer aspire one 722](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131170/how-to-get-microphone-to-work-on-acer-aspire-one-722)

Answer (score 19):

1. Open a terminal
2. Run `alsamixer` (pictured in original question)
3. Use left/right arrow keys to select "Auto Mut"
4. Use up/down arrow keys to Disable Auto Mute
5. ESC exits

https://superuser.com/questions/431079/how-to-disable-auto-mute-mode
http://www.tutonics.com/2012/10/fix-no-sound-turn-off-auto-mute-in.html

To save settings try `sudo alsactl store` (untested)

[Howto save AlsaMixer settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50067/howto-save-alsamixer-settings)

This fixed my sound problems with Ubuntu 12.10 on a ThinkPad x230

alsa version : `cat /proc/asound/version`

Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version 1.0.25

Comment: I think it should be noted that you may have to scroll to the right to view (if Terminal is not maximized) the auto-mute option. I was scratching my head for a bit... Thanks, it worked! I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Lenovo Y510P.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the method pertaining to disabling Auto-Mute mode in alsamixer (or gnome-alsamixer) didn't work. So, I dug it deeper and found a similar thread here [My headphones mute AlsaMixer when I plug them in, HP DV6 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280566/my-headphones-mute-alsamixer-when-i-plug-them-in-hp-dv6-12-04)

In my case, I had the problem that plugging headphones in would switch the speaker sound to zero as well as mute it (which is correct and should definitely happen); and when you disconnect the headphones, the headphones would be muted. Moreover, the speaker volume after connecting and disconnecting headphone wasn't getting saved.

What I did was make changes to files in `/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths`, specifically the files named `analog-output-headphones.conf` and `analog-output-speaker.conf`.

Before proceeding, you should take a backup of these files in case anything goes wrong.

For `analog-output-speaker.conf`, I searched for `[Element Headphone]` directive and removed `switch = off` line, and changed `volume = zero` to `volume = merge`.

For `analog-output-headphones.conf`, I searched for `[Element Speaker]` directive and removed `volume = zero` line, while keeping the `switch = mute` line.

I couldn't get the `mute-on-activation` to work on connection of headphones so that it temporarily mutes the headphones while the 3.5mm jack isn't fully plugged in. I'd update the answer accordingly if anyone comments with a way to do so.

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line in your `rc.local` file in order to disable Auto-Mute in each boot.

```
/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled
```

---

For example:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

then it would be like below:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/usr/bin/amixer -c 0 sset "Auto-Mute Mode" Disabled

exit 0
```

Comment: `/etc/rc.local` doesn't exist on my system, Kubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. A replacement is to [use systemd, eg via an `rc-local.service`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/471824/what-is-the-correct-substitute-for-rc-local-in-systemd-instead-of-re-creating-rc).