# No sound or sound card not detected in Dell Precision WorkStation T7400

Tags: 10.04, sound, dell, hda-intel

I have got Ubuntu 10.04 Server Edition running on a Dell Precision T7400 Workstation with an Intel Sound card

`Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: AD198x Analog [AD198x Analog]`

and I am trying to get the sound working on the system, but the sound is not working.

On typing `lspci` at the prompt, all I get is [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1091562/)

Comment: What cable do you use I use hdmi and had to open settings then sound and select my card from a list of about 10 have a look see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, there is a preferences dialog for audio settings. Search for audio settings in the Applications & Preference Menu.

Now you should see a window with some preferences. Try to select different sources and outputs.

Comment: Tried both selecting my sound card as well as changing options under Preference Menu. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Inspiron and i got the sound working with Ubuntu 14.04 doing "killall pulseaudio" in the terminal.
[No sound in Ubuntu except at log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-except-at-log-in)