# Help me with my sound

Tags: 12.04, sound

My sound card is recognized and I have tried every troubleshooting tactic on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting and using all the tactics from [No sound in Ubuntu except at log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04). I just recently reformatted my computer to run only Ubuntu 12.04, before that I was running Windows and Ubuntu 11.10. My sound wasn't working then, and I thought reformatting my hard drive would have helped, but it didn't. Also, the sound works perfectly when I use my headphones or other auxiliary output device, but never when I want to use my computer speakers.

Comment: Did you make sure the Speaker channel is not muted? Did you make sure the speakers are connected correctly?

Comment: @mikewhatever the speaker channel is not muted. The speakers are on 100%. Both of those above threads had me check that and, according to my system, the speakers are at full volume.

Comment: Please tell us what hardware you have (sound card).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, When I type in
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
I get
lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 82801I (ICH9 Family) HD Audio Controller (rev 03)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device 20f2
 Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
 Memory at f2620000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
 Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
As a response. I think that is how I was told to find out my what my sound card is...