# ubuntu 12.04 LTS no sound

Tags: 12.04, sound

I just reinstalled ubuntu 12.04 from a DVD that came in the Ubuntu User magazine. I previously had 13.04 but had decided to revert back to the LTS. Now with 12.04 I have no sound when I try to play my music, I tried using Musique and also Rhythm Box they both show playing with the slider but no sound is heard except if the volume is all the way up you can hear a faint hiss or static. Any advice on how to fix this?  Thanks

Harlie

Comment: Possible duplicate: [No sound in Ubuntu 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to a variety of problems. I have had success diagnosing sound issues with this [Sound Troubleshooting Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iTlJ8BfqXUjaHO__TEdlkvuqB1WLOkGaudngc5SFLMI/edit) before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday on 14.04 and [this](http://itsfoss.com/fix-sound-ubuntu-1404/) worked for me.  Like the comments say, make sure you add in a third line

> defaults.ctl.card 1