# No sound in 12.04 LTS ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I recently took an old Dell with Windows XP and installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I completely erased XP in favor of Ubuntu. I noticed on a youtube video it won't play any sound. Then I realized it won't play sound at all. Anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: No luck. Not muted either.

Answer (score 0):

Open a **Terminal** by pressing **Ctrl+Alt+T** and type the following command:

```
sudo rm -rf /home/YourUsername/.pulse
```

or

```
sudo rm -rf /home/YourUsername/.config/pulse
```

Be careful to check where is the `pulse` directory in your `home` folder. This will remove the **PulseAudio** configuration files. And then restart your system using:

```
sudo reboot
```

I had this problem a time ago and this solved my issue. I see that there are many other users who solved the issue this way, because I made some searches over the Internet.

Or check this link – [No sound in Ubuntu except at log in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04?rq=1)