# speakers not working

Tags: sound, speakers

I can hear the sound from my laptop speakers on the startup but after that when I try to play any music on VLC I don't hear any sound. I can't even hear any sound on youtube so it's not the problem with VLC. If I try running any sound by Guest user then it works.

Comment: Try running "/usr/bin/pulseaudio" in terminal.

Comment: jatin@jatin-HP-ProBook-445-G1:~$ /usr/bin/pulseaudio               
E: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.                     
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: pa_pid_file_create() failed.                                     @KunalSangwan

Comment: As stated below, try "alsamixer" in terminal. Sometimes the problem is that alsa somehow got muted,So I guess try disabling Auto-Mute Mode. The mute can be toggled with the M key.

Comment: Run "pavucontrol"  and go to the "Output Devices" tab (3rd tab) while you play the video.  There is a level meter right above the "Advanced" option. While you play the audio, does the Level Meter fluctuate?

Answer (score 1):

Tried`alsamixer` in terminal? Remove all of the M's by using the cursor keys to navigate below an output labeled as MM and tap M to unmute it. The cursor up and down keys can also be used to adjust the volume if necessary.

[image: alsamixer]

---

For more possible answer's, see here:
[No Sound in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing works,reinstall the audio system.
Run the following code:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Hope that helps. !