# No Sound/Audio on new Ubuntu Install

Tags: sound, via

I am installing Ubuntu 13.10 on my PC , but the sound device is not working.
It works fine in Windows 7.
The VIA Audio driver is needed to be installed in Windows 7 to work.
Is there a Linux VIA driver somewhere?

Comment: You should consider looking at http://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-12-04.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one audio device.

You have to select your sound card in Sound configuration

righ click in sound applet, then click in sound configuration. Then select your card