# No sound with HP 500-016 running Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound

I have searched quite a lot looking for a solution. Here is the sound info from the terminal.

Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 01)

I believe the problem is that my computer has the DVI-D connector that requires an adapter to connect an HDMI cord. The connector doesn't output audio so I bought a 3.5mm stereo to red/white rca cable for the audio.

The audio worked with a previous install of Ubuntu, sorry I can't remember the release.
(Long story I was trying to get Win 8 and Ubuntu to work together...that's another F^&%king nightmare)

Please Please help. I have been using Ubuntu for about 5 years and other than when I need to use a couple specialty hardware items I never even bother with Windows.

Comment: I got Windows 8 pre-installed OEM version and Ubuntu 14.04 dual booting successfully now. If you have upgraded to Windows 8.1, then you will not be able to install it successfully. I kept getting a vfat error for the Windows 8.1 EFI partition whenever installing. However, after I overwrote the Windows 8.1 with Windows 8 image, installation of Ubuntu 14.04 was very smooth. Like you, I am wrangling with the audio issue now.

Comment: possible duplicate of [No sound in Ubuntu except at log in](http://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-except-at-log-in)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Terminal and run `alsamixer`. From there, go to Auto-mute and set it to "Disabled".

Then go to LoopBack and select "Enabled".  That worked for me. If it does not for you, try other combinations.

atonit.