# No sound ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa

I was playing video, and suddenly it stops working.
I did run `alsamixer`, and it shows:

[image]

Speakers are not mute, still there is no voice, headphones are working fine.
Can anyone tell me what's wrong with sound or is it a hardware failure?

Comment: Did you try to connect speakers to some other source (phone, another computer) to check if they are not broken?

Comment: I had the same problem and I found out somehow a package named "ubuntu-touch-sound" is installed. after I purged it, computer works like a charm. have you checked sound packages?

Comment: @user596137 yes i connected

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem. It worked after I disabled the **< auto-Mute >** option in the alsamixer. It is shown on your picture on the right side. 
Have also a look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132577/no-sound-in-ubuntu-except-at-log-in) (second answer)

Comment: This might be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try resetting the configuration of pulseaudio by running:

`rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k` and then do a reboot.