# no sound in headphones on hp dv6 6154tx in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, sound, hp-pavilion

i have installed ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop hp dv6 6154 tx , but no sound is coming from earphones although the speakers are working fine.

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems something like this: [My headphones mute AlsaMixer when I plug them in, HP DV6 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280566/my-headphones-mute-alsamixer-when-i-plug-them-in-hp-dv6-12-04)

I had this problem and I only did what is written there:

> Edit `sudo gedit
>   /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output-headphones.conf`
>
> and modify the `[Element Speaker]` section as follows:
>
> ```
> [Element Speaker]
> ; link to muting
> switch = mute
> ; set volume to zero, so only the master slider controls playback volume. This gives better linearity.
> volume = zero
> ```
>
> After this, I had to restart the system: you might try to restart only
>   pulse audio with `pulseaudio -k`.

Comment: Then, mark my answer as the solution.