# No sound from speakers when headphones plugged in even after switching output device, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, 20.04, headphones, speakers

So i have tried to use pavucontrol, where i can see "Line Out (plugged in)" and "Headphones (plugged in)". My problem is that the sound is output to the headphones when they are plugged and when i try to switch output to the line out on the speakers - there is no sound at all. BUT(!) if i unplug the headphones then the sound in the speakers appears. How can i fix it? By the way, a coule of days ago i tried Linux Mint (20) and there were no problems with switching audio output.

p.s. I've read several similar topics, but in them the cases are slightly different

Comment: I was wrong about Linux Mint, there is the same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your problem are solved after this long but I just want to share the solution for other people seeing this.

I just disable auto-mute in alsamixer.

Here is how: https://askubuntu.com/a/282640/1739995

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).